# How do I say "The only way" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

How do I say "The only way" in German?

> Die einzige Art und Weise, Deutsch zu lernen, ist mit Deutschen zu reden.

Is there another alternative for this?

Comment: Es gibt nicht nur Deutsche die Deutsch als Muttersprache haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also say:

> Die einzige Art ...
>   Die einzige Möglichkeit ...

Or even

> Der einzige Weg ...

The latter sounds strange in some contexts and is mostly used when you can replace *Weg* by *Ausweg*. You could, for example, say:

> Ich muss *xyz*. Das ist der einzige *[Aus-]* Weg *[aus dieser Situation]*.

Comment: I'd actually say that "Weg" is the best choice... "Weg" implies success here, while "Möglichkeit" doesn't. A course can be a Möglichkeit but not a Weg. Art is odd too since it is more about a manner of doing something, not about doing something to begin with. They work too but "Weg"'s the best.

Comment: Is "die einzige Weise" possible too?

Comment: It is used rarely. I know it only in sentences like *Ich habe das auf die einzige Weise gemacht, die mir eingefallen ist.*